# Alfresco SDK code hanging at AuthenticationUtils.startSession

Tags: sdk, alfresco, bitnami

i am testing the code from SDK to call Alfresco on bitNami Alresco 4.0.e-0 server with a webapp that is located on same tomcat server as Alfresco. The code hangs at the very first call to AuthenticationUtils to get session. I pretty am sure i supplied the standard bitNami Alfresco user and password for this. Did i miss any libraries? I put most available dependencies as my local maven repositories and code compiles well.

the following is code from SDK without Alfresco license as i could not format the code with it:

```
package org.alfresco.sample.webservice;

import org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Store;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.WebServiceFactory;

public class GetStores extends SamplesBase
{
/**
 * Connect to the respository and print out the names of the available 
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws Exception
{
    // Start the session
    AuthenticationUtils.startSession(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    try
    {   
        // Get the respoitory service
        RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub repositoryService = WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService();

        // Get array of stores available in the repository
        Store[] stores = repositoryService.getStores();
        if (stores == null)
        {
            // NOTE: empty array are returned as a null object, this is a issue with the generated web service code.
            System.out.println("There are no stores avilable in the repository.");
        }
        else
        {
            // Output the names of all the stores available in the repository
            System.out.println("The following stores are available in the repository:");
            for (Store store : stores)
            {
                System.out.println(store.getScheme() + "://" + store.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // End the session
        AuthenticationUtils.endSession();
    }
}       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebServiceFactory uses

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api
```

as default endpoint.You can change the endpoint by providing a file called **webserviceclient.properties** on the classpath under **alfresco** (the resource path: alfresco/webserviceclient.properties)

The properties file must offer a property called **repository.location**, which specifies the endpoint URL. Since you are using a bitnami Alfresco instance, it is probably running on port 80. The file should contain the following property entry:

```
repository.location=http://localhost:80/alfresco/api
```

Comment: Thanks. I could not locate that file but in another file called repository.properties i saw the setting and used it in my code. Also, looking in catalina-daemon.out, i found some libraries are missing for the call to go through. Added them and i am good now. Thanks a lot